# GLOBAL THRESHOLDING using histogram

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, homework, histogram, thresholding

[image: histogram]

There is a recursive way of finding threshold in the image using histogram that are biomodal, and is as follows:

An automated procedure for bimodal histograms :

1. Select an initial estimate of T
2. Compute the means of the two regions determined  by T
3. Set the new T as the average of the two means
4. Repeat steps 2,3 until the difference in T in  successive iterations is smaller than a predefined  parameter

I have an old exam question below and I dont know how to solve it. all I know the T is $114$ and if this also helps total number of pixels are area first triangle+are of second triangle area + 4000 pixels. I am stuck on how to calculate step 2 to get me going.

### Old Exam Question

explain why the isodata threshold of image is equal to $114$.

Comment: If this is a question for a real exam you're taking, we can't solve it for you.

Comment: Well this is not a exam question that I am taking , It is old exam paper which is available online on university database. I  appreciate more not to give a full solution but to give a hint to get me going. like this I learn.

Comment: @Phonon could you please unhold this question?

Comment: All good. We're just trying to be careful with content.

Comment: For step 2, split the data into two pieces: samples < 114 and samples >= 114. Compute the means of each piece.

Comment: OK I think the mean of  < 114 and samples >= 114 will be the peak of each triangle since they look like a Gaussian distribution , am I right?